# Where is studying the Bispectrum useful?

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, moments, spectral-analysis

In cosmology it is well known that studying the bispectrum of the large scale structure of the universe is a powerful way to distinguish different models of cosmic initial conditions. I had assumed that the bispectrum had endless applications in many areas of science and data analysis more generally but when I tried to search for applications I found very little.

Perhaps I should be looking for applications of higher order statistics more generally? Is there some other terminology I could try searching? If anyone can point me in the direction of some interesting applications I would be very grateful.